# getServletContext NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I know this question has been asked a million times and there are 5 million answers - some or which are very informative.  None of which have solved this problem.

My goal is similar to many of the others - I want to access files - images, svgfiles, templates, etc. in the web app run-time environment.  I can make it work if I simply hard wire the directory path.  However, I would like to make my servlet portable and use a relative reference to access these resources -if for no other reason I develop in Windows and deploy in Linux.

The basic problem is that getServletContext() is null and I am unable to determine why.

Below is the error message, the code that produced it, followed by environment details.  Produces the same error in both development and production. I will be happy to provide any additional details if requested.

**Please explain what I need to do to get this working? I will be eternally grateful.  Regards**

```
     SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/HelloWorld] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /hello.jsp at line 19

     16: <title>Hello World</title>
     17: </head>
     18: <body>
     19:  <%=wtGreet.getGreeting()%> 
     20: </body>
     21: </html>


    Stacktrace:] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)
at HelloWorld.Greeting.getGreeting(Greeting.java:23)
at org.apache.jsp.hello_jsp._jspService(hello_jsp.java:91)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

HelloWorld application works - produces undesired error - exactly the same as the real thing.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF 8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="wtGreet" scope="page"
class="HelloWorld.Greeting">
<jsp:setProperty name="wtGreet" property="who" value="World"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="wtGreet" property="greet" value="Hello"/>
</jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="wtGreet" property="*"/>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
 <%=wtGreet.getGreeting()%>
</body>
</html>
```

Then Servlet that the jsp calls

```
package HelloWorld;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class Greeting extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1298516959968350334L;
    private String who;
    private String greet;

    public void setWho(String who) {
        this.who = who;
    }

    public void setGreet(String greet) {
        this.greet = greet;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        System.out.println("getServletContext() == null :" + getServletContext().getContextPath());
        return "<p>" + this.greet + " " + this.who + "</P>";
    }
}
```

**Development Environment**
Windows
Eclipse JEE
Apache
Tomcat 7
JRE 7

**Production Environment**
Linux
Apache
Tomcat 7
JRE 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the last element of your stack trace

```
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)
```

the method `getServletContext()` is called and the exception happens in the line `125` in the class `javax.servlet.GenericServlet`.

If `getServletContext()` had returned `null` then the last stack trace element would have been

```
at HelloWorld.Greeting.getGreeting(Greeting.java:23)
```

According to this [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ovea.tajin.server/tajin-server-tomcat7/1.0.b6/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.java) of `javax.servlet.GenericServlet` the method `getServletConfig()` is the one returning `null`, i.e. you servlet is not configured.

This might be because you are (mis)using a servlet as a bean in your jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="wtGreet" scope="page" class="HelloWorld.Greeting">
```

and that servlet is not properly initialized.

Servlets are not meant to be used like that. You may want to use a simple [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) and have it have a method `getGreeting()`.

To get the `ServletContext` inside your jsp you may use the implicit object `application`, See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) for other available implicit objects in the jsp.

Comment: You correctly perceived core of my misconception.  This helped me frame my research to get to the answer.  The basic solution is centered on the concept of Model 1 vs Model 2.  Where I have implemented an accidental model somewhere in between but not really conforming to any model (my premise was MVC - separate view from model).  My understanding is that Model 2 is the prevailing best practice and therefore my goal is to implement this pattern.  I would appreciate any perspective that you might be able to share regarding this.  Regards.

Comment: Relevant reference for anyone who is interested:  [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the final solution is to implement a Model 2 pattern (I will include when finished), there is a good working answer for the question as asked.  Thanks to A4L for showing the way.

Working from the understanding that the jsp engine compiles the jsp into a servlet and loads it into the servlet engine, the jsp implicit objects can be used to access an instantiated javax.servlet object.

The HelloWorld example is changed as follows:
1) Remove import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; and extends HttpServlet because this does nothing.
2) Add an attribute of type ServletContext and populate the attribute using the setter from the jsp page.

Any object that is available to the servlet can be available to the bean by way of jsp implicit objects.

jsp

```
{<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="wtGreet" scope="page"
class="HelloWorld.Greeting">
<jsp:setProperty name="wtGreet" property="who" value="World"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="wtGreet" property="greet" value="Hello"/>
</jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="wtGreet" property="*"/>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<%wtGreet.setSc(application.getContext("/HelloWorld"));%>
<%=wtGreet.getGreeting()%>
</body>
</html>}
```

Bean

```
package HelloWorld;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
public class Greeting {
private String who;
private String greet;
private ServletContext sc;
public void setSc(ServletContext sc) {
    this.sc = sc;
}
public void setWho(String who) {
    this.who = who;
}
public void setGreet(String greet) {
    this.greet = greet;
}
public String getGreeting() {
    return "<p>" + this.greet + " " + this.who + " from \"Context Path\" " + sc.getContextPath() + "</P>";
}
}
```